# XSLT sort output csv data

Tags: sorting, xslt

My task is to transform xml data to csv (comma separator data).
I have problem with sorting in the output data.
Please look at my examples below.

Please provide any suggestions how to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance!

**INPUT XML DATA**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
  <ItemInfo>
    <ItemNmb>Item1</ItemNmb>
    <ItemText>Item 111</ItemText>
    <ItemDetails>
      <ItemDetailInfo>
        <id>111</id>
        <Text>Text 111</Text>        
      </ItemDetailInfo>
      <ItemDetailInfo>
        <id>555</id>
        <Text>Text 555</Text>        
      </ItemDetailInfo>     
    </ItemDetails>    
  </ItemInfo>
  <ItemInfo>
    <ItemNmb>Item2</ItemNmb>
    <ItemText>Item 222</ItemText>
    <ItemDetails>
      <ItemDetailInfo>
        <id>555</id>
        <Text>Text 555</Text>        
      </ItemDetailInfo>
      <ItemDetailInfo>
        <id>333</id>
        <Text>Text 333</Text>
      </ItemDetailInfo>
      <ItemDetailInfo>
        <id>222</id>
        <Text>Text 222</Text>
      </ItemDetailInfo>
    </ItemDetails>
  </ItemInfo>
  <ItemInfo>
    <ItemNmb>Item3</ItemNmb>
    <ItemText>Item 333</ItemText>
    <ItemDetails>
      <ItemDetailInfo>
        <id>999</id>
        <Text>Text 999</Text>
      </ItemDetailInfo>     
    </ItemDetails>
  </ItemInfo>  
</Root>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>


  <xsl:param name="delim" select="';'"/>
  <xsl:param name="break" select="'&#xA;'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">

  <xsl:for-each select="/Root/ItemInfo">
      <xsl:call-template name="itemtemp">
          <xsl:with-param name="item" select="ItemNmb"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="ItemText"/>         
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="itemtemp">
    <xsl:param name="item"/>
    <xsl:param name="text"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="ItemDetails/ItemDetailInfo">
      <xsl:sort select="id" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="copmitemtemp">
        <xsl:with-param name="item" select="$item"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$text"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="idsub" select="id"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="textsub" select="Text"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="copmitemtemp">
    <xsl:param name="item"/>
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="idsub"/>
    <xsl:param name="textsub"/>


    <xsl:value-of select="$idsub" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><xsl:value-of select="$delim"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$textsub" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><xsl:value-of select="$delim"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$item" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><xsl:value-of select="$delim"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$text" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><xsl:value-of select="$break"/>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT DATA**

```
111;Text 111;Item1;Item 111
555;Text 555;Item1;Item 111
222;Text 222;Item2;Item 222
333;Text 333;Item2;Item 222
555;Text 555;Item2;Item 222
999;Text 999;Item3;Item 333
```

**EXPECTED RESULT** (Is sorted by (id))

```
111;Text 111;Item1;Item 111
222;Text 222;Item2;Item 222
333;Text 333;Item2;Item 222
555;Text 555;Item1;Item 111
555;Text 555;Item2;Item 222
999;Text 999;Item3;Item 333
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the sorting should be done by `ItemInfo/ItemDetails/ItemDetailInfo/id` therefor you need to iterate over `ItemDetailInfo`.
Try this slightly change version of your xslt.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>


    <xsl:param name="delim" select="';'"/>
    <xsl:param name="break" select="'&#xA;'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:for-each select="/Root/ItemInfo/ItemDetails/ItemDetailInfo">
            <xsl:sort select="id" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="copmitemtemp">
                <xsl:with-param name="item" select="../../ItemNmb"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="../../ItemText"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="idsub" select="id"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="textsub" select="Text"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="copmitemtemp">
        <xsl:param name="item"/>
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="idsub"/>
        <xsl:param name="textsub"/>


        <xsl:value-of select="$idsub" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$delim"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$textsub" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$delim"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$item" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$delim"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$break"/>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate the following output

```
111;Text 111;Item1;Item 111
222;Text 222;Item2;Item 222
333;Text 333;Item2;Item 222
555;Text 555;Item1;Item 111
555;Text 555;Item2;Item 222
999;Text 999;Item3;Item 333
```